# Wordpress Widget - Saving multidimensional arrays into $instance

Tags: wordpress

In my wp widget, `$instance` has an attribute called `order` which will the listing order of libraries/services. I'd like to store a multidimensional associative array that will hold the id of each location/service, its type (i.e. if it's a location or a service), and it's name. I'd like it to look something like this:

```
 array(
     [0] => ( 'id' => 1, 'type' => 'location', 'name' => 'University Library'),
     [1] => ( 'id' => 7, 'type' => 'service', 'name' => 'Circulation Desk') );
```

Below is the html markup for the wp widget admin pane and `$instance['order']`:

```
<label>
  <?php _e( 'Select ordering', 'olh' ); ?>:
</label>

<select
  name='select-hours-order'
  class='select-hours-order'>
  <!-- dynamically populated by jQuery -->
</select>

<a 
  class='add-location-service'>
  <i>+</i>
</a>

<ul
  name='<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ) ?>[]'
  id='<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'order' ) ?>'
  class='location-service-order' >

  <?php 
    foreach ($instance['order'] as $order ) : ?>

    <li
      class="<?php echo $order['class'] ?>"
      value="<?php echo $order['value'] ?>">
      <?php echo $order['name'] ?>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

The user can choose what locations/services s/he wants to display with a multi-select dropdown. Whenever the user selects a library/service, it automatically populates `select.select-hours-order`. The user can then click the `+` button of `a.add-location-service` to add it to `ul.location-service-order`.

From there, I'd like to save the `li`s of `ul.location-service-order` with the attributes I specified above.

Thank you gals/guys for any and all info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a workaround to solve this problem. Instead of attempting to store a multidimensional array as described above, I instead store a simple array of values created by combining the type with the id.

So, instead of:

```
array(
   [0] => ( 'id' => 1, 'type' => 'location', 'name' => 'University Library'),
   [1] => ( 'id' => 7, 'type' => 'service', 'name' => 'Circulation Desk') );
```

The array becomes:

```
array( 'L1', 'S7' );
```

For the list items, I nested a *hidden input* inside the list item that will has the name attached and the value I want to store, like so:

```
  <?php 
    foreach( $instance['order'] as $order ) : 
      if( $order ) : ?>

        <li value='<?php echo $order ?>'>
          <span> Library name. </span>
          <input 
            type='hidden'
            name='<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ) ?>[]'
            value='<?php echo $order ?>'
          />

          <a class='destroy_parent'>X</a>
        </li>

  <?php 
    endif;
  endforeach; ?>
```

Notice the `input`'s name and it's value. The `[]` at the end of the name indicates that an array of values will be stored.

Comment: After having spent a long day on this stupidity, I'd like to thank you very much for this input!